# MySQL foreign key to table list

Tags: php, mysql

Lately I have been doing some work with MySQL and have come across the need to store table names as a field in one of my tables (which is not ideal). Instead I would like to reference a list of tables that currently exist in the database as a foreign key. I have found that the information_schema database stores a list of these tables however I cannot reference them as a foreign key as they are Memory tables. Is there another way I can reference the list of tables in the database as a foreign key.

For those interested, the reason I need to store the table names is because I am developing a basic PHP framework that exposes each table in the database as a class.

Answer (score 0):

How dynamic is the list of tables in your database? One option is to create your own table and (periodically) fill it with the table names from information_schema.

Comment: In one of my previous implementations I had a table doing exactly as you said. However I'm currently in the process of trying to simplify the way the code works, hence I removed that table and was hoping to foreign key to a pre-existing list of tables (e.g. like that found in the information_schema).